# Cosmos Fiware and Webhdfs API

Tags: fiware

I signed up in Fiware and created an account for Cosmos.

I was able to ssh on the head node, but I coulnd't use the API for webhdfs or cosmos.

I used curl on my ubuntu shell like this:

> curl -i
>   http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/username?[user.name=username&password=*********]op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY

I wasn't able to get any response from that, though.

Can someone point me what I might be doing wrong here? Am I forgetting anything?

Answer (score 0):

We have deployed a [HttpFS gateway](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html) at FILAB, which listens in TCP/14000. This HttpFS hides the datanodes and only the namenode is reachable, but the WebHDFS API remains the same.

Please observe your curl's or application calls must be done from a FILAB VM as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about if I want to call the API from a vm running a node server outside of FILAB?

Comment: It should be dropped by our firewall.

Comment: Just an update: currently the access is allowed outside FIWARE Lab as well.